# SimpleCursorAdapter IllegalArgumentException: column does not exist

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have read similar posts but none of this used external db as i do.Here is my problem.Firtsly i had the below code and worked fine :

```
public class ArchaeologyMuseums extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_archaeology_museums);
    String[] from = new String[]{"museum_name", "museum_category", "museum_open_now", "museum_distance"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_name, R.id.item_category, R.id.item_open_now, R.id.item_distance};
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;

    }


    Cursor c = myDbHelper.getArchaeologicalData();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, c, from, to);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);}}
```

Then i changed my db and added 3 new columns: museum_name_greek, museum_category_greek, museum_greek_hours and used the code below:

```
public class ArchaeologyMuseums extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_archaeology_museums);
    String[] gr = new String[]{"museum_greek_name", "museum_greek_category", "museum_greek_hours", "museum_distance"};
    String[] from = new String[]{"museum_name", "museum_category", "museum_open_now", "museum_distance"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item_name, R.id.item_category, R.id.item_open_now, R.id.item_distance};
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    String locale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;

    }


    Cursor c = myDbHelper.getArchaeologicalData();

    if(locale.equals("el")) {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, c, gr, to);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);}

    else {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, c, from, to);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);}}}
```

So if locale is "el" i get IllegalArgumentException: column museum_greek_name does not exist.I tried with 2 different cursor calls (c,c_gr) but no fix.Any suggestion?

Comment: if you have `museum_greek_name` column in db later then make sure you are passing incremented version for database version

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Should i use this? I have added other columns which work fine without this.I just delete the old and copy the new one db inside assets folder.

Comment: uninstall your previous application and install new

Comment: @kamran thnx man...fixed...